# How to handle single quotes in Postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

When I am trying to find all records in `details` table which have `Linux` present in the array column `operating_systems`.

Query `select * from details where 'Linux' = ANY(operating_systems);` works perfectly and returns all records which have `Linux` in `operating_systems` column.

But if I want to get all records where `I don't know` is present in `operating_systems` I am unable to form a correct query.

Query `select * from details where 'I don\'t know' = ANY(operating_systems);` does not escape single quotes and takes it literally, resulting in an incomplete query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that single quotes can be escaped by adding another single quote before it. So `select count(*) from details where 'I don''t know' = ANY(operating_systems);` works.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 2):

> Found that single quotes can be escaped by adding another single quote before it. So `select count(*) from details where 'I don''t know' = ANY(operating_systems);` works.

This is acceptable for ad-hoc queries, or queries where a data literal is hard coded.

It's *absolutely not OK* if the string comes from an application user. Do not do this. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for why.

*Use parameterised queries* (often incorrectly called *prepared statements*, though they're not quite the same thing). Exactly how to do that depends on your programming language and client, which you have not mentioned, but it usually involves "preparing" a statement then executing it with parameters.